# SQL Server or CSV File(s) to PDF's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, pdf, ms-word

From what I have read via google, it may be possible to do this with Rails? But I sadly don't know where to begin.

I have been asked to understand if it is possible to either utilising SQL Server or multiple CSV dumps to create a PDF of customer sales orders for the year.

An example of data I am working with is as follows;

[image]

What I need is a way to go through each ClientID in turn, Create a new page for each 'Category' Type of purchase as separate sequentially numbered PDF's so that Page 1 for client A1 would only have the motorcycle, page 2 would have the two helmets as that then completes that data entry for the client.  I would need to save the two PDF pages as a single document entitled A1 and save this to C:\PDFOrderCreation

Constraints:

- There can be no more than 10 lines of data per page,
- There is a header and footer which have to remain static on the page(s)

I don't know where to begin with this, I have considered trying to do it with word but it would I think be extremely messy and resource heavy.

Anyone have any thoughts or able at least to push me in the right direction?

Comment: You don't want to use Word in a server environment. Theoretically, you could generate Word documents using the Open XML file format, but those would need to be converted to PDF, which would mean Word Automation Services. Might as well write directly to PDF, possibly using a tool...

Answer (score 1):

you would have to write a software that queries your SQL server and creates pdf files. There are many ways to do this, but afaik it cant be done using only SQL server features, SQL server is meant to store and serve your data, what you want to do with this data is out of it's scope. your software would have to do 3 things:
1. To query the data from your server
 2. To organize the data in the structure you need it to be presented
 3. To write it to pdf files
You would have to target each task individually, and it can be done using either a web application or a native application which could be written in ruby, c#, java, js,c++, objective c or any other programming language. Its important to note that TSQL is NOT a programming language, its a query language. Good luck!

Comment: The OP's question is really broad. I'm an expert in PDF. I've written a PDF library available in Java and C#. I can assure you that it's not trivial. The OP will have to start looking for an existing PDF library.

Comment: since he mentioned ruby i checked what they have in ruby, and a very short search brought up https://rubygems.org/gems/pdf-writer/versions/1.1.8 . pdf is so common these days that its very hard for me to believe that in any wide spread language there isn't a solution for writing PDFs. And from hard experience i agree - at least the first time you do it its not a trivial task at all

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie BTW, iTextSharp is awesome. thank you